# Can Elementary OS be added in the help section for topics not to ask about?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

currently the list of off-topic subjects include the following:

> Linux Mint, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04) and other Linux distributions (try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).

I want Elementary OS to be added here as well. Since it's off topic and quite popular, of course we can't list everything that's off topic but the most popular distributions should be here.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen  spike in numbers of Elementary OS questions.

Comment: Certainly we seem to get more Elementary OS questions these days, than Backtrack and off-topic Gnome-Remix questions.

Comment: I've updated the help section

Answer (score 5):

I agree; the list of example off-topic distros should be updated from time to time to reflect those that are most commonly asked about. This is beneficial not merely because it helps people using those specific distros know to ask their questions elsewhere, but also because current and popular examples tend to make good, illustrative examples.

**I suggest we replace the text "Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04)" with the text "Elementary OS."**

I believe off-topic Gnome-Remix questions are uncommon now compared to several OSes not listed.

I think removing "Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04)" as part of the same change that adds "Elementary OS" would be good for two reasons:

- It would control the length and complexity of the help pages (especially compared to just having the list of unofficial distro examples grow and grow over time). This is good because it may increase the likelihood people will read and understand it.
- Keeping dated, now-uncommon examples of what not to ask about may fool people into thinking, "well I've heard a lot about how Mint isn't supported, and these other distros are obscure ...*my* distro is probably okay."

Why have I not simply upvoted this question and posted a separate one asking for "Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04)" to be removed? Because:

- That we can remove old examples is the *reason* there are no significant disadvantages to adding new ones. I'm much more convinced it would be good to "Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04)" with "Elementary OS" than that it would be good to just tack "Elementary OS" onto the current list.
- There's probably no good reason to make two changes to (the same sentence of) the same help page, one after another, if they can just both be made at the same time.

Comment: I agree with a lot of what you say, but the point of this question wasn't just to add elementary os to the list it was to improve the sentence as a whole. I think it should be something like this: **For questions regarding Linux Mint, Elementary OS and backtrack go to our friends at Unix & Linux instead.**

Comment: "the list of example off-topic distros should be updated from time to time to reflect those that are most commonly asked about. " I disagree on this. An "off topic" list seems not the correct way to go to me since there are ubuntu spin-offs released every hour. A list should be conclusive and not open ended. The sentence should be **For questions other than Ubuntu, lUbuntu,(insert all other official releases) go to our friends at Unix & Linux instead** The idea should be to change that sentence whenever Ubuntu gets expanded with a new flavour.