# Should Elementary OS be added to the flag text "This is not about an official Ubuntu flavor."?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons

To make it more clear, here's the flag page/fly-out thing:

[image: flag dialogue]

(Pardon the coloration, as I use a dark theme for the site.)

In the very top-most option, it has links to *Unix & Linux*, *Super User*, etc.

It's still in beta, and I'm not sure if that status matters, but Elementary OS has its own StackExchange site [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/) and has had it for a while now.

Should Elementary OS be added to that dialogue?

It may make more people aware that it exists and may lower the number of questions we get about Elementary OS. Of course we can just ship them off to the Unix & Linux site, as we currently do. At the same time, it may be a better idea to send them somewhere more specific when the opportunity arises.

On the other hand, it may make absolutely no difference at all *and* the Elementary page is still in beta. It may also start a trend where we'd have to have the text changed every time another Linux distro gets a SE site of its own. That could end up rather verbose.

Related:
[Can Elementary OS be added in the help section for topics not to ask about?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11890/can-elementary-os-be-added-in-the-help-section-for-topics-not-to-ask-about)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

We have a very limited amount of space for statements in close reasons - if we could fit other OSes there we probably would but we are out of space in that reason's length to do that right now.  We have space for only 69 characters more on that close reason - if we expanded to include eOS and others we won't have the space to include them all - which is why we simply say "This is not Ubuntu" and point people to U&L for other Linux distros (Mint, eOS, etc.)

Comment: That makes sense. I figured verbosity would potentially be an issue. I'll just continue to link it via comments when it's appropriate.